# Synchronization Between Two SQL CE 3.5 Databases

Tags: synchronization, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework, embedded-database

This is a continuation to the post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6711/using-sync-orchestrator-to-syncronize-two-sql-ce-3-5-databases)

I am trying to set up synchronization between two SQL Compact 3.5 databases using SqlCeSyncProvider.  My provisions are set up correctly (I believe), but when I try to insert a row into either database and call syncOrchestrator.Synchronize(), I get the following error:

```
A column named '__sysTrackingContext' already belongs to this DataTable.
```

Which is the InnerException to the error:

```
Cannot enumerate changes at the RelationalSyncProvider for table 'Person'.
```

I have read the post [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/syncdevdiscussions/thread/187efac4-6506-48dd-bcd6-581b9d28c17d) which seems to address the same issue, but I am using Sync Framework v2.1 and disabling change tracking does not seem to have any affect.

How do I resolve this error?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: have you tried deprovisioning and reprovisioning both databases?

Comment: This happens when I first set up provisioning with new databases.

Comment: are you using GetDescriptionForTable against a provisioned SQL CE database? if you are, the GetDescriptionForTable maybe picking up the change tracking columns as columns to be synched.